# Not able to register device with MFP8.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are developing ionic app with mfp8.0. We are using the following code to connect with mfp server,

```
var Messages = {
  // Add here your messages for the default language.
  // Generate a similar file with a language suffix containing the translated messages.
  // key1 : message1,
};

var wlInitOptions = {
  // Options to initialize with the WL.Client object.
  // For initialization options please refer to IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Knowledge Center.
  onSuccess:function(){alert('success')},
  onFailure:function(){alert('fail')}
};

function wlCommonInit() {
  app.init();
}

var app = {
  //initialize app
  "init": function init() {
      app.testServerConnection();
  },
  //test server connection
  "testServerConnection": function testServerConnection() {
    WL.App.getServerUrl(function (url) {
    });

    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
      .then(
        function (accessToken) {
          alert('accessToken   '+JSON.stringify(accessToken));
          isPushSupported();
        },
        function (error) {
           alert('Error   '+error);
        }
        );
  },

}

function isPushSupported() {
    MFPPush.isPushSupported(
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Push Supported: " + successResponse);
            registerDevice();
        }, function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to get push support status");
        }
    );
}

function registerDevice() {
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.registerDevice(
            {"phoneNumber":""}, // workaround due to a defect in the current release of the product. An empty "phoneNumber" property must be passed at this time.
            function(successResponse) {
                alert("Successfully registered");
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to register");
               alert("Failed to register device:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
            }
        )
    );
}
```

We can able to connect with mfp server. But, We unable register device for push notifcations. We are getting the following error,

```
"com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException:Response:Status=404, Text:Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404\r\n, Error Message : Not Found"
```

(or)

```
"com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException:Response:Status=500,Text:{\"errorCode\":\"UNEXPECTED_ERROR\",\"errorMsg\":\"Unexpected Error Encountered\"}, Error Message : Unexpected Error Encountered"
```

*Actually, We are getting this error recently. Before that the same code was working fine for us.*

**Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function of Register Device accordingly.
Please go through the link:
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js

```
function registerDevice() {
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.registerDevice(
            null,
            function(successResponse) {
                alert("Successfully registered");
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to register");
               alert("Failed to register device:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets do not show how did you try to register your application to the push service...

Did you follow the instructions of the push tutorial and looked at the sample push applications before opening a question?

See the tutorials and samples, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/

Comment: It was working from long back. suddently, its not working. Thats what I have raised this question.

Comment: Make sure you are using an updated SDK and server instance. With the latest SDK you no longer require the phoneNumber workaround - see the cordova tutorial for the updated API.